# python unicode in subprocess does not work same in console and in mod_wsgi

Tags: python, subprocess

On a python console I can run (echo of e acute):

```
import subprocess
cmd = u'echo "é"'
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

But if I run that code in a Django view (mod_wsgi), It crashes :

```
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 444, in call
     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
 TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

I can solve this problem by doing a `.encode('ascii','replace')` but it strips the accentuated chars.

I cannot see any way to specify a locale or an encoding while calling the subshell. I tried to configure mod_wsgi with lang and locale to utf-8 but it did not help.

How can I run a subprocess call with accentuated chars on mod_wsgi ?

Comment: What locale is the subshell set to? That you managed to use a Unicode string without explicitly encoding works *at all* is actually surprising. Pick an explicit encoding, and set the locale for the subshell explicitly. Or tailor the encoding to the tool you are calling.

Comment: I cannot see any way to specify a locale or an encoding while call the subshell. I also tried to translate to utf-8 the command : there is still the problem. I also tried to configure mod_wsgi with lang and locale to utf-8 but it did not help.

Comment: What is the real command? `echo` is hardly useful in `mod_wsgi`. The shell will inherit the locale (`LC_*` and `LOCALE` environment variables) from Python which in mod_wsgi controls; there appears to be a [way to set those](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html) but I haven't tried that myself yet.

Comment: I made a mistake : I used decode instead of encode for 'utf-8', works better now ... Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way :

```
subprocess.call(cmd.encode('utf-8'),shell=True)
```